# Extract text from document name using calculated column

Tags: sharepoint-designer, calculated-column, metadata, string

I need to isolate parts of a document name so that the workflow (SPD 2010) can update respective metadata fields.

Doc Name is within the following format : yyyymmdd.xxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxx.xxxxxxxx

The need is to extract 3 metadata fields within the name of doc shown above. I want to create calculated columns to go about doing this but getting stuck. I know that we can use string functions, however, the find string within string function is not available via SPD 2010 wf's and our current 2013 version is not working (ticket open with MS but client needs workaround).

Comment: Two things: Is this method required for managing metadata? Or can you use another method (Such as making a taxonomy via the Managed Metadata service)? And are the `yyyymmdd.xxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxx.xxxxxxxx` format all the same length (eg, is the second metadata always 4 characters, and the third matadata always 8 characters?

Comment: The character length will always be consist. And at the moment, we're just trying to create the same instance as that with the 2013 process so as not to change the process for the users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using LEFT and RIGHT, you could just use MID.

Returns "JUNK" from the KGlasier example.

```
=MID( [Doc Name], 10,4 )
```

MID( string, startChar, numberOfChars )

Comment: Nice! Didn't know about MID. +1

Answer (score 1):

To extract the metadata values from the `Doc Name` column you can use the `=RIGHT(<TEXT>,<LENGTH>)` and `=LEFT(<TEXT>,<LENGTH>)` functions. As long as the length of each metadata is the same (Where `yyyymmdd.xxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxx.xxxxxxxx` is always of lengths 8.4.8.4.8) then these formulas should work...

```
// If [Doc Name] is 20180917.JUNK.JAZZLIKE.QUIZ.BLIZZARD

=LEFT(
   RIGHT(
      [Doc Name],
      LEN([Doc Name])-9
   ),
   4
)
// Returns JUNK

=LEFT(
   RIGHT(
      [Doc Name],
      LEN([Doc Name])-14
   ),
   8
)
// Returns JAZZLIKE

=LEFT(
   RIGHT(
      [Doc Name],
      LEN([Doc Name])-23
   ),
   4
)
// Returns QUIZ

=LEFT(
   RIGHT(
      [Doc Name],
      LEN([Doc Name])-28
   ),
   8
)
// Returns BLIZZARD
```